# RDLC Subreports

Tags: c#, rdlc

Is it possible to use an IIF statement to choose which subreport is used? I have two subreports, one of which is always hidden based on a report parameter, but an empty line still shows up when one of them are hidden.

Comment: any luck solving this one? I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, I am not aware of any method for doing so. I think you will have to use a trial-and-error approach to solving the empty line issue. In my experience these annoying formatting issues often crop up for obscure reasons. Try changing the padding or sizes of the objects surrounding or in the vicinity of the subreports. If that does not work then try creating and placing a 3rd subreport on the main report which contains the original two subreports so that you have only one subreport on the main report.